# Meshes joined in Blender are still un-joined in Nifscope

Tags: objects, export

I created a posing character as static meshes from a body with a skeletion. It shows up fine in Oblivion. I want to join all the meshes that make up the body (upper, lower, etc)  so i can quickly paste this newly created single mesh into another .nif, or otherwise manipulate it. The meshes were  joined in Blender with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.
It seems to have exported with no problems, since it shows up in game with no problems.  However, the meshes are still shown as separate pieces in nifscope, so I have to copy and paste each piece to move it. So evidently, importing to Blender, joining the meshes, then exporting is not the solution.

Nifscope 1.1.3 rev 36bfdd/
Blender 2.49b

Comment: what is the reason you are using 2.49? blender is up to 2.75.

Comment: Games are sometimes more compatible with specific Blender builds. I use TES Oblivion engine.

Comment: Note that such old builds are not as readily supported, and bugs will most likely not be fixed.

Comment: Here is a link to an answer that works, I had the same problem. https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/108199-help-needed-with-blender-or-nifskope/